# Does 付き合ってやる mean To date(romantic) or to just go with someone somewhere?

Tags: meaning

付き合ってやる is this romantic or platonic ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: It depends on the context, as any dictionary can tell.

Answer (score 3):

It quite depends on the case. Without context, it is hard to tell, but it sounds most likely nothing related to romance.

It is because in the romantic case, 付き合ってやる sounds like `I can go out with you for your sake`, which is quite weird, for me at least. It only makes sense in the situation where you're so much confident that the person is in love with you and you're (or, you want to pretend to be) not so willing to go out with him/her.

So, I guess 付き合ってやる is most likely meaning `I can do whatever you want together with you for your sake` (possibly without willingness). There's no romance or love. It's crudely showing kindness.